# How to correct close and delete database link in java program?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

My java program create database link in Oracle , then select data from it.
In the end it tries close database link
 by ALTER SESSION CLOSE DATABASE LINK linkname and delete it.
But I catched exception with - ORA-02080: database link is in use.
If tried to drop link without closing, following exception will be catched - 
ORA-02018: database link of same name has an open connection.
How correct close and delete database link?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check https://odenysenko.wordpress.com/2017/03/09/explicitly-closing-oracle-database-link/ for what needs to be done to close a database link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before deleting database link, I have reopen DB connection, to close session and this help me. Also closing session will help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a COMMIT; before trying to close the Database Link?

The select you run opens a transaction that needs to be commited before you can close the db link.

Comment: I tried perform commit or rollback before closing link, but it didn't help. Could you please provide an example?